# VPS questions - newbie

Tags: linux, centos, debian, vps

I have a site that accumulated high traffic so Im thinking of moving to VPS hosting.
but I am a complete newbie with linux. so I have some questions:

1. what is the recommended OS for VPS? most searches show CENTOS or
   Debian.
2. What platform is recommended? 64bit / 32bit  ?
3. what are the basic installation necessary for an operational VPS (web server) ?
4. what are the extra recommended installation?

I want to first try to install locally on virtualbox, so any suggestions for a good guide will be appreciated.
10x.

Comment: There are also Windows VPSs.  Or "Cloud hosts", like Amazon or Microsoft Azure. FYI, my VPS happens to be CentOS.  But there's really little/no practical difference from your point of view.  "Debian vs. Centos" is unimportant.  Price, disk storage, CPU ... and technical support ... are all much more important considerations.  IMHO...

Comment: thanks for replying. of course you are right. just wondered if a certain build has an advantage.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the recommended OS for VPS? most searches show CENTOS or
>   Debian.

Both CentOS and Debian are excellent operating systems, if you choose either of them, you won't go wrong.  Debian is certainly rocksolid OS with great security track-records. However, Since you are new with Linux machines, you would need some sort of control panel to manage the Linux machine.Hence, I would recommend CentOS box with cPanel for easy startup.

> What platform is recommended? 64bit / 32bit ?

Of course 64 Bit Operating system.

> what are the basic installation necessary for an operational VPS (web
>   server) ? What are the extra recommended installation?

cPanel will include all necessary tools and software to run web server. However, if you wish you can install firewall or other required tools through terminal. Also, you can try out CentOS in virtual box easily, for cPanel, you would need license and static IP address.